# Problem with Difference-in-differences with variation in treatment timing - bacondecomp

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `bacon` function of the `bacondecomp` library.

I have a panel of observations treated at different point in times (staggered) and I would like to get the Goodman-Bacon Decomposition to understand how much heterogeneity there is in the treatment effect.

When I run the `bacon` I obtained the following error message which I do not understand:

```
Error in create_treatment_groups(data, control_vars, return_merged_df = TRUE) : 
  Treatment not weakly increasing with time
```

I have balanced the panel that looks like:

```
              id time outcome_var treated_var other_var
01012-2001 01012 2001           0           0               -0.7475860
01012-2002 01012 2002           0           0               -2.5542758
01012-2003 01012 2003           0           0               -1.2759632
01012-2004 01012 2004           0           0               -0.1647962
01012-2005 01012 2005           0           0               -0.8171105
01012-2006 01012 2006           0           0               -0.6549951
```

and using the following code:

```
df_bacon <- bacon(outcome_var ~ treated_var,
+                   data = pdBal,
+                   id_var = "id",
+                   time_var = "time")
```

I have 18 years and 14358 units of observation. 32759 units are treated all over the period.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you in advanced
AP

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by looking at the code!

I had problems with the treated variable. Some units were treated for some years, but not treated for some years in the middle of the sample (so the switch back from being treated).

Comment: Glad, that you solved your problem. However, you might want to elaborate how you changed your code to solve the issue. That might help others as well.

Comment: Sure! I have just removed from the dataset the units for which treatment turns on/off.